# What I must understand from this if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

What I must understand from this if statement:"if(!n>5 && 1>=++i) ++n;"

````
What is the output?

main()
{ int i=0,n=5;
if (!n>5 && 1>=++i) ++n;
printf("%d %d",i,n); }```
````

Comment: Two things you need to know: Logical AND and OR (`&&` and `||`) uses [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation); And `++i` increments `i` *first* and returns the new value.

Comment: The most important thing to know is not to code like this.

Comment: If `n == 5` then `!n == 0`. So with short-circuiting, nothing else is evaluated.

Comment: Oh, and [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) is also very important to know.

Comment: This looks like a homework question and StackOverflow is not a homework solving service.  If you can ask a specific question and indicate what progress you made toward solving it on your own, you may get some useful help.  Note that you can, and should, test your guesses yourself by compiling and running the code and/or slightly modified versions of it.

Comment: @Umut Arda Kapan I am sure you must understand only one thing: each programming language requires a time to learn it.:)

Answer (score 2):

Order of precedence is important: `!n>5` is not the same as `!(n>5)`, but it is actually `(!n)>5`

As `!` is a logical negation it will always result in 0 or a non-zero value which may always a fixed value like 1, in which case `!n` is never going to be `>5`

So the statement after `if (!n>5 && 1>=++i)` will never be run as the first condition (`!n>5`) is never true.

You should use brackets and write something like `if (!(n>5) && 1>=++i)` or `if (n<=5 && 1>=++i)`.